# Requirements to configure Reporting services during TFS installation

Tags: sql, reporting-services, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I can't find this answer anywhere and maybe I'm just not getting it.  I am installing TFS 2013.3 and I no matter what wizard I choose, there is no option to configure reporting services.

Environments tried:

1. Windows 7 Enterprise / MS SQL 2012 Express / TFS 2013.3 Express
2. Windows 8 Professional / MS SQL 2012 Developer / TFS 2013.3 Standard

I am about to try on a Windows Server 2012 SP1 machine shortly in case it has to be a server level machine.  I looked on the MSDN for hardware and software support for both SQL/TFS and the above configurations are ok.

Pre-configuration tasks

1. SQL server pre-installed
2. SQL configured with Reporting and Analysis services enabled
3. User to install and configure both SQL and TFS is in the local Admin group
4. Used both the Basic and Advanced wizards during setup

I'm not sure what I am missing, but it seems that not doing something to be able to use the built in reports.  It doesn't look like I need SharePoint for that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592.aspx):

> You can install Team Foundation Server on a client computer that is
>   running one of the operating systems in the table. However, client
>   operating systems **do not support** integration with SharePoint Products,
>   **reporting**, or the ability to run TFS proxy. ...
>   If you want to use any of these features, you must install Team
>   Foundation Server on a server operating system.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks!  Right below the darn matrix of client machines.  Well I missed it!  It doesn't quite jump out at you.